# pure javascript toggle meni flickering

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle

trying to create a pure javascript toggle menu, but its flickering, any suggestions? sorry no jquery please.
    var getToggleId = document.querySelector('button.menu_button');
    var getMenubyId = document.getElementById('menu');
    var myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

```
function clickToggle(e){
var el = e.target;
if(el.className ==="menu_button"){
    if(getMenubyId.style.visibility == 'visible' && myWidth <= 600){
    getMenubyId.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
        getMenubyId.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
 }
};

getToggleId.addEventListener('click', function(e){
clickToggle(e);
}, false);

function screenSize(){

if(window.innerWidth > 600 && getMenubyId.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
    getMenubyId.style.visibility = 'visible';
}else{
    getMenubyId.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
};
window.addEventListener('resize', screenSize, false);
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? That would make this easier to help you with.

Comment: For starters, the screenSize function will always toggle visibility. If its hidden, it will make it visible, if its visible, hidden.